# change kerning of \texttt

Tags: fonts, kerning, typewriter

I tried to use a font different than courier for monospaced fonts but none of this list (http://www.ctan.org/topic/font-mono) are available on my system - and as we work in a distributed system custom local additions are not an option. (Build server, standards, etc.)

so question is

1. is there a usullay available monospace font, that is more condensed, i.e. needs less horizontal space?
2. how can i reduce the general kerning for all letters in \texttt or the whole font?

Comment: `\texttt` itself has no kerning statement. I fear, you have to change the font rather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways: 1) with `microtype`'s `\textls` macro, and the other, `\spaceout`, without any packages. I have wrapped those macros into `\textttA` and `\textttB` invocation forms.

The `\textls` macro uses an optional argument to specify the compression or expansion, while `\spaceout` uses the values of `\theLetterSpace` and `\extraWordSpace` to modify the default spacings.

Both approaches support line wrapping.

Summarizing from the comments below, it is worth noting that the `\textls` approach supports hyphenation, whereas the `\spaceout` approach does not.  In addition, the argument to `\spaceout` cannot include a macro that itself takes an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\theLetterSpace{-0.5pt}
\def\extraWordSpace{-0.5pt}
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \def\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\kern\extraWordSpace\ \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\parskip 1ex
\usepackage{microtype}
\def\textttA#1{\texttt{\textls*[-70]{#1}}}
\def\textttB#1{\texttt{\spaceout{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\def\mytext{a bit of texttt}
This is \texttt{\mytext}\par
This is \textttA{\mytext}\par
This is \textttB{\mytext}\par
\def\mytext{a bit of texttt. a bit of texttt. a bit of texttt. a bit of texttt. 
a bit of texttt. a bit of texttt. a bit of texttt. a bit of texttt. }
\noindent\hrulefill\sloppy\par
This is \texttt{\mytext}\par
This is \textttA{\mytext}\par
This is \textttB{\mytext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although not wanted as comment: wow. Now my head is fried from overload. Have to test it.

Comment: Just to be sure, that I get your magic right: This is a recursive pattern that with A separates on spaces and kerns the word separation and with B kerns every two characters.
So it is a macro, that effectively inserts a `\kern{…}` before every single letter?
Cool :)

Comment: would it make sense to define the kerning in measures of `ex`?

Comment: @Jan Yes, "A" parses by the word and kerns before each space, while "B" parses by the letter and kerns after each letter.

Comment: @Jan Actually, ex is a vertical font measure.  If one wanted to use scalable horizontal font measure, em would be the choice.  If you plan to use it over different point sizes, that might be a good idea.

Comment: interstingly, `\textls` not only enables line wrapping, but also hyphenation. Not completely intended :)

Comment: good to know about ex being vertical, while em being horizontal. Thanks

Comment: @Jan I should add that `\spaceout` will choke on an argument that includes macros which themselves take an argument.  Thus, `\itshape` is OK in an argument, but `\textit{a bit of text}` is not OK inside a `\spaceout` argument.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, that `\spaceout` does not enable hyphenation